# Retrieve full name of teacher for which all of his/her students have max score

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having issues trying to retrieve the full name record of the teacher(only 1 record) for which all of his/her students have a maximum score(6). Here are the following 3 tables:

Students table:

| student_id | teacher_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |

Teachers table:

| teacher_id | full_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NameA |
| 2 | NameB |
| 3 | NameC |
| 4 | NameD |

Scores table:

| student_id | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |

What I expect when having a proper query here is to retrieve a single row with 'NameB' teacher.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT t.full_name 
FROM students s 
INNER JOIN teachers t 
ON s.teacher_id = t.teacher_id 
WHERE s.student_id = 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(sc.student_id) 
      FROM scores sc 
      WHERE s.student_id = sc.student_id 
      AND sc.score = 6 
      GROUP BY sc.student_id
    );
```

When having only 1 teacher with students who have max score I am getting that teacher with the following query. But when I tried to test and have a second teacher which students have max score the query is not working.

Thanks a lot for your attention and time.

Comment: One option is to use NOT EXISTS and so exclude all teachers who have student(s) with other scores.

Comment: @JonasMetzler: or you can use EXISTS to check if all students have a 6.

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) then edit your question and show what you have tried and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: why one record only?  what if there are multiple teachers with all their students having max scores?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add the query I have tried, I have edited my question, don't think I haven't tried and asking for a solution. An advice is enough.

Comment: @ysth Yes if there are multiple teachers with all their students having max score it would be more than 1 record, thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: You should also (try to) explain why your statement is not producing the requested result. When you try to explain that to yourself you will see that your current statement is not correct. (It compares `s.student_id` with a `count(sc.student_id)`, and when will a  COUNT be equal to a student_id ?.....

Comment: HINT: Currently you are returning the teacher for student 1, which happens to be the correct answer.....

Comment: Yes but we have that score for both student 1 and 3 and if we adjust the table to have another teacher's students  for example 3 students with score 6 it still returns this one.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say that you are returning the teacher for student who has exactly 1 time scored a 6. (Please ignore my previous bad description....)

Comment: Have a look at this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/RnVMDoAH)  When you study it long enough you will learn what is wrong....

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know why but when I alter a different teacher to have more than 2 times score 6 for example I am still getting the one with 2 times score 6 instead the one with 2 times along with the one with 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the teacher of which all of his/her student have `only` 6 score you can use `HAVING NOT SUM(score <> 6)` which will filter out all records which have a score different than 6.

Try:

```
select distinct t.full_name
from teachers t
inner join students s on t.teacher_id=s.teacher_id
inner join scores sc on sc.student_id=s.student_id
group by t.full_name
HAVING NOT SUM(sc.score <> 6)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/qOrrVjuA

Comment: I want to retrieve the records for all the teachers that have all of their students with max score 6. And for example if we have more than one teacher with all of their students having only score 6. We should receive 2 records.

Comment: @ciconq try the updated query

Comment: Thank you very much @Ergest Basha, tested it out with various combinations and it works as expected.